# Home Server Restore

Tags: backup, restore, windows-home-server

I have had to reinstall Home Server on my server and I would now like to restore it back to the state it was the last moment it stopped.

I have the hard drive in a state it was last in, which is a small 250 gb hard disk.  I have now installed 1.5tb hard disks, and installed a full licenced copy, as the original copy was a trial version.

So I'm in a state where I have a new install, I have one of the old drives plugged in, but I can't transfer the old backups across, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you dedicate a disk for the server backup? If so you shou7ld be able to add it back as a server backup disk and restore from it. IF you did not the backups are of your clients not the server.